# Dialogs generic function - return boolean based on user button press

Tags: android, android-dialog

I would like to write a function that would show a alert dialogue box which returns boolean based on the button clicked

```
private Boolean ShowWarningMessageBox(String Title, String message)
{
    boolean returnValue = false;

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            getApplicationContext());

    builder.setTitle(Title);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
            returnValue = true;
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    returnValue = false;
                }
            });

    builder.show();

    return returnValue;
}
```

I have written the above function but the problem is, Inner class will not be able to access the returnValue variable as it is not final. But making it final does not serve me my purpose.

I am a c# developer and I am trying to achieve something like below in android

```
private DialogResult ShowWarningMessageBox(string errorMessage)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(errorMessage,
                 Resources.WarningCaption.ToString(),
                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk,
                 MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

        return result;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: you need to use interface for that

Comment: Even if you could access the returnValue, it would be false every time. Because it is returned after showing the dialog, not when clicking the Button. And if it would wait until a Button is clicked, you'd get an ANR because the Thread sleeps until the button gets clicked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Complete solution Try this**

**1) Createa Interface**

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;

public interface AlertMagnatic {

    public abstract void onButtonClicked(boolean value);

}
```

**2) Generalize method for confirm dialog.**

```
public static void getConfirmDialog(final Context mContext,
            final String title, final String msg,
            final String positiveBtnCaption, final String negativeBtnCaption,
            final boolean isCancelable, final AlertMagnatic target) {

        ((Activity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

                int imageResource = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert;
                Drawable image = mContext.getResources().getDrawable(
                        imageResource);

                builder.setTitle(title)
                        .setMessage(msg)
                        .setIcon(image)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton(positiveBtnCaption,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        target.onButtonClicked(true);
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton(negativeBtnCaption,
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                            int id) {
                                        target.onButtonClicked(false);
                                    }
                                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.setCancelable(isCancelable);
                alert.show();
                if (isCancelable) {
                    alert.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                            target.onButtonClicked(false);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

**3) How to use**

```
getConfirmDialog(getString(R.string.logout), getString(R.string.logout_message), getString(R.string.yes), getString(R.string.no), false,
                new AlertMagnatic() {


                    @Override
                    public void onButtonClicked(boolean value) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I am getting an error at  alert.show(); and log shows as pasted here http://pastebin.com/VXreEWef

Comment: from where you calling this dialog?

Comment: dont pass getApplicationContext() use ActivityName.this instead and I edit the method take update and check

Comment: This is excellent! Why isn't something like this available in the Android API's!?

Comment: In case anyone else also wants this: Add "TextView messageText = (TextView)alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
          messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);" below alert.show(); to centre the text.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks very much. One question, is there anyway to extend this to except in any number of buttons (e.g. .setItems(new CharSequence[]{"button 1", "button 2", "button 3", "button 4"}). And if so, how will I know which one was pressed within the class it's called from (i.e. in your above sample you have the "how to use" that overrides the onButtonClicked, is there a way to override another function that will give me the child number (e.g. button1) that was clicked)???

Comment: i too tried it but i didnt get the expected result as i worked like any other simple dialog.. It didnt wait for my response . method returned the value from below without waiting for my response on the dialog box